# How to split an XML tag using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have a source XML which is like this (as shown below) in which there is one PR tag under which there can be multiple Pr Line tags but in the final XML i want the source XML  (containing multiple Pr Line tags) to be split as shown in the target xml.

Source:

```
  <PRSet>
   <PR>
    <PRNUM>100</PRNUM> 
    <VENDOR>XYZ LLC</VENDOR> 
    <PRLINE>
      <PRLINENUM>101</PRLINENUM>
      <DESCRIPTION>Burner Lamp</DESCRIPTION> 
    </PRLINE>

    <PRLINE>
      <PRLINENUM>102</PRLINENUM>
      <DESCRIPTION>Stove</DESCRIPTION>
    </PRLINE>
   </PR>
  </PRSet>
```

When multiple PRLine Tags are there in a single PR tag then the final xml should look like this:

Target:

```
<PRSet>
 <PR>
  <PRNUM>100</PRNUM> 
  <VENDOR>XYZ LLC</VENDOR> 
 <PRLINE>
  <PRLINENUM>101</PRLINENUM>
  <DESCRIPTION>Burner Lamp</DESCRIPTION> 
 </PRLINE>
</PR>

 <PR>
  <PRNUM>100</PRNUM> 
  <VENDOR>XYZ LLC</VENDOR> 
 <PRLINE>
  <PRLINENUM>102</PRLINENUM>
  <DESCRIPTION>Stove</DESCRIPTION>
 </PRLINE>
</PR>
```

Can anybody provide the solution how to achieve this using XSLT Transformation.
Many Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transformation that you describe can be achieved with the following XSLT stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="PRSet">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="PR/PRLINE" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="PRLINE">
        <PR>
            <xsl:copy-of select="../PRNUM|../VENDOR|." />
        </PR>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```